# OSX Mutt Mailcap Not Viewing text/html

Tags: email, html, email-client, mutt

I have installed Mutt on OSX. I am trying to configure Mutt to view HTML emails. I have added an `auto_view` directive and mailcap file. However whenever I open an email in html it simply shows up as text.

My configuration files:

`~/.muttrc`:

```
set imap_user = 'REDACTED'
set imap_pass = 'REDACTED'

set smtp_url = 'smtps://REDACTED@REDACTED'
set smtp_pass = 'REDACTED'
set record=""

set folder = imaps://REDACTED/
set spoolfile = +INBOX
set record = "REDACTED"
set postponed = "REDACTED"
set mbox="imaps://REDACTED"
set trash="imaps://REDACTED"

auto_view text/html
```

`~/.mutt/.mailcap`:

```
text/html;  elinks -force-html %s
text/plain; less
```

I thought the mailcap file might be in the wrong place so I also tried moving it to `~/.mailcap`, `~/.mutt/.mailcap`, and `~/.mutt/mailcap` but with no success.

I have also tried adding `; needsterminal` into my mailcap file for the `text/html` line.

I tried opening a HTML file I had with the `elinks` command in the mailcap file and it succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

`set mailcap_path = <PATH>`